# AngularJS id attribute in the included HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In AngularJS, the id attribute from my HTML Template isn't recognized by my javascript.

For example :

index.html file :

```
<div ng-controller="SubwayMapController">
   <div subway-map></div>
</div>
```

scripts.js file :

```
app.directive('subwayMap', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'Views/subway-map.html'
        };
    });

        map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
        var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
        var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
        var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(2.35,48.85).transform( fromProjection, toProjection); //Paris
        var zoom           = 12; 

        map.addLayer(mapnik);
        map.setCenter(position, zoom );
```

subway-map.html file :

```
<div id="basicMap"></div>
```

When I open index page, I expect the map from Openstreetmap to be displayed but nothing happens.

Comment: I think you have to wright your map code in link function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting up the map in the `link()` function of the directive. Plus, it looks like you can `Map.render()` using a DOMElement instead of needing an ID.

```
app.directive('subwayMap', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'Views/subway-map.html',
            link: function(scope, element) {
              var map            = new OpenLayers.Map();
              var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
              var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   
              var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
              var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(2.35,48.85)
                                       .transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
              var zoom           = 12; 

              map.addLayer(mapnik);
              map.setCenter(position, zoom );
              map.render(element[0]);
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: I set up the map in the `link()` function of the directive. I get an Angular error `this.div.appendChild is not a function` and an Openstreetmap error `this.div.style is undefined`.

Comment: You are going to have to play with it a little, with no fiddle and all. Probably you need to use `element[0]`. Updated.

Comment: Ok, I tried with `element[0]` and I get no more errors. But the map doesn't show. I'll play with it a little.

Comment: Thank you @Malk, your solution works for me. I had to change the css from `%` to `vw` and `vh` for the map to be displayed. `px` works too.

Answer (score 0):

put map access code in setTimeout. You are trying to access the map immediately . Angular ain't done with map rendering yet , so `setTimeout` is the solution.

```
    $timeout(function(){
         map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
            var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
            var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
            var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
            var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(2.35,48.85).transform( fromProjection, toProjection); //Paris
            var zoom           = 12; 

            map.addLayer(mapnik);
            map.setCenter(position, zoom );
    },10);
```

Comment: Better to use Angular's `$timeout`, not `setTimeout`.  It's not necessary to wait half a second; a zero-duration `$timeout` is enough to defer this code to the next digest loop.

Comment: Do I also put this `$timeout` in my closure function ? `(function () { ... })();`

Comment: Why use `$timeout` when you could just use `ng-onload="renderMap()"` It seems an arbitrary timeout would be a fragile approach.